# Django runserver doesn't do anything after system check with no error

Tags: django

I have a blog written using django 1.9. 
Now I'm trying to move to django 2.2.

When I run `python manage.py runserver`, the system check finds no error. But it exits without starting server.

**Output:**

```
(blog) borg@borg-TravelMate-P258-MG:~/githubRepo/Blog/Blog$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8887
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
(blog) borg@borg-TravelMate-P258-MG:~/githubRepo/Blog/Blog$
```

Since there is no any exception printed, I have no idea how to solve it right now.

Comment: Follow [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/upgrade-version/) official document to upgrade your django version.

Comment: 1.9 to 2.2 is a big jump. Try to get it working on Django 1.11 first, and fix any deprecation warnings before upgrading to 2.2. Amongst other things, you’ll have to fix the `MIDDLEWARE` settings.

Comment: It seems that a segmentation fault caused the python interpreter to crash.

Comment: Now I'm sure it's caused by mysql backend. Maybe I'm missing something when setting up my environment.