# Django Runserver Crashes without Message

Tags: django

I've been working a project for months using Python3 & Django, never had issues regarding starting django but yesterday I formatted my Mac, I have the project in Github so today I clone the project and had bunch of issues with Psycopg2 and Pillow but eventually fixed it.

The problem now is that, when on the terminal I put `python manage.py runserver`, django simply crashes without any message and I don't know how to find the problem or view any logs regarding the crash, this is all I get:

```
(backend) ➜  src git:(master) ✗ python manage.py runserver
3Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...
```

After that it simply crashes and nothing else happens. Any ideas on how to debug this problem? I've tried cloning it again and building it but same results.

Comment: Did you have a virtualenv implemented before you formatted your Mac?

Comment: Yes. I always use virtualenv.

Comment: So did you backup your virtualenv to run it again? Or are you even in the virtualenv when the error occurs?

Comment: I didn't backed it up, but my project contains a requirements file holding all the apps needed to run. I even cloned it on a different pc and everything works smoothly, I know the problem is on my pc, but I don't know how to debug the error since I'm not getting any message when it crashes.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55981844/django-runserver-doesnt-do-anything-after-system-check-with-no-error

Comment: Tried that and no luck yet.

Comment: In case some else is experiencing problems with MacOS Catalina and their python projects, use Python 3.6.5, I was using Python 3.7.5 and it was impossible to run some python projects. Rolledback to 3.6.5 and now works like a charm.

Comment: ;) well done, happy it works